# Maximum number of network updates retrieved per API call

Tags: rest, linkedin-api

Is there any restriction on the number of entries that are retrieved using a single call to the Network Updates API? I found this forum comment  "The per-user limit is per call, so 300 requests with however many updates they have." on the thread

http://developer.linkedin.com/forum/increase-search-api-throttle-limit

I want to confirm that indeed there is no limit. I have received as many as 106 entries in a single call.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maximum number of updates returned from the [Network Updates API](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/get-network-updates-and-statistics-api) appears to be 250. Performing the following query as an example:

http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/network/updates?count=500

Even if I try to specify the `start` parameter at, say, 250, I can't get the next 250 updates from the API:

http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/network/updates?count=250&start=250

So it looks like 250 is the max, with no ability to page beyond that.

UPDATE:

Have verified that 250 is the maximum number returned, either in a single call or via the paging parameters. Looks like the documentation has been updated to reflect this.

Comment: Is there any documentation for this? FWIK I believe you are an LIemp. Can I take this to be the official rule, or is it a bug imposed limitation that will be fixed?

Comment: Not official, above determined through testing, bug filed on behavior.

Comment: @user1514989 FYI, confirmed the behavior is by design, 250 is the maximum value, whether it's paged or not.